# Speeding up datetime.strptime

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, profiling, strptime

I am using the following piece of code to extract a date from a string:

```
try:
    my_date = datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
except ValueError:
    my_date = None
```

If I run this 750,000 times, it takes 19.144 seconds (determined with cProfile). Now I replace this with the following (ugly) code:

```
a= 1000 * int(input_date[0])
b=  100 * int(input_date[1])
c=   10 * int(input_date[2])
d=    1 * int(input_date[3])
year = a+b+c+d

c=   10 * int(input_date[5])
d=    1 * int(input_date[6])
month = c+d

c=   10 * int(input_date[8])
d=    1 * int(input_date[9])
day = c+d

try:
    my_date = date(year, month, day)
except ValueError:
    my_date = None
```

If I run this 750,000 times, it only takes 5.946 seconds. However, I find the code really ugly. Is there another fast way to extract a date from a string, without using strptime?

Comment: Use `timeit` to do time trials, not `cProfile`. I am not saying that the cards will fall differently, but it'll certainly be more accurate.

Comment: Why not e.g. `year = int(input_date[:4])`? What is the `try` guarding against - invalid formats may fail on the indexing.

Comment: @martijn: The reason I'musing cProfile: I need approximate results of all my methods, not just this one.

Comment: @physicalattraction: but **in this post** you are talking about this one. If you want to run time trials to compare approaches to a single task, use `timeit`.

Comment: @physicalattraction: and for the record: strptime is indeed slower (by about 2x) than your ugly approach, because it does much more validation on the input. It can handle months and days that are not zero-padded, for example.

Comment: @jon: The year = int(input_date[:4]) is indeed a good tip, I am using it now. It even speeds it up more (to 3.3 seconds). I guess I have to place those commands within the try as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are faster methods to parse a date than `datetime.strptime()`, if you forgo a lot of flexibility and validation. `strptime()` allows both numbers with and without zero-padding, and it only matches strings that use the right separators, whilst your 'ugly' version doesn't.

You should always use the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) for time trials, it is far more accurate than `cProfile` here.

Indeed, your 'ugly' approach is twice as fast as `strptime()`:

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime
>>> import timeit
>>> def ugly(input_date):
...     a= 1000 * int(input_date[0])
...     b=  100 * int(input_date[1])
...     c=   10 * int(input_date[2])
...     d=    1 * int(input_date[3])
...     year = a+b+c+d
...     c=   10 * int(input_date[5])
...     d=    1 * int(input_date[6])
...     month = c+d
...     c=   10 * int(input_date[8])
...     d=    1 * int(input_date[9])
...     day = c+d
...     try:
...         my_date = date(year, month, day)
...     except ValueError:
...         my_date = None
... 
>>> def strptime(input_date):
...     try:
...         my_date = datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
...     except ValueError:
...         my_date = None
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('f("2014-07-08")', 'from __main__ import ugly as f')
4.21576189994812
>>> timeit.timeit('f("2014-07-08")', 'from __main__ import strptime as f')
9.873773097991943
```

Your approach can be improved upon though; you could use slicing:

```
>>> def slicing(input_date):
...     try:
...         year = int(input_date[:4])
...         month = int(input_date[5:7])
...         day = int(input_date[8:])
...         my_date = date(year, month, day)
...     except ValueError:
...         my_date = None
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('f("2014-07-08")', 'from __main__ import slicing as f')
1.7224829196929932
```

Now it is almost 6 times faster. I also moved the `int()` calls into the `try` - `except` to handle invalid input when converting strings to integers.

You could also use `str.split()` to get the parts, but that makes it slightly slower again:

```
>>> def split(input_date):
...     try:
...         my_date = date(*map(int, input_date.split('-')))
...     except ValueError:
...         my_date = None
... 
>>> timeit.timeit('f("2014-07-08")', 'from __main__ import split as f')
2.294667959213257
```