# Fast conversion of timestamps for duration calculation

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

We've got a log analyzer which parses logs on the order of 100GBs (my test file is ~20 million lines, 1.8GB). It's taking longer than we'd like (upwards of half a day), so I ran it against cProfile and >75% of the time is being taken by strptime:

```
       1    0.253    0.253  560.629  560.629 <string>:1(<module>)
20000423  202.508    0.000  352.246    0.000 _strptime.py:299(_strptime)
```

to calculate the durations between log entries, currently as:

```
ltime = datetime.strptime(split_line[time_col].strip(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
lduration = (ltime - otime).total_seconds()
```

where `otime` is the time stamp from the previous line

The log files are formatted along the lines of:

```
0000 | 774 | 475      | 2017-03-29 00:06:47 | M      |        63
0001 | 774 | 475      | 2017-03-29 01:09:03 | M      |        63
0000 | 774 | 475      | 2017-03-29 01:19:50 | M      |        63
0001 | 774 | 475      | 2017-03-29 09:42:57 | M      |        63
0000 | 775 | 475      | 2017-03-29 10:24:34 | M      |        63
0001 | 775 | 475      | 2017-03-29 10:33:46 | M      |        63
```

It takes almost 10 minutes to run it against the test file.

Replacing `strptime()` with this (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626354/speeding-up-datetime-strptime)):

```
def to_datetime(d):
    ltime = datetime.datetime(int(d[:4]), 
                              int(d[5:7]), 
                              int(d[8:10]), 
                              int(d[11:13]), 
                              int(d[14:16]), 
                              int(d[17:19]))
```

brings that down to just over 3 minutes.

cProfile again reports:

```
       1    0.265    0.265  194.538  194.538 <string>:1(<module>)
20000423   62.688    0.000   62.688    0.000 analyzer.py:88(to_datetime)
```

this conversion is still taking about a third of the time for the entire analyzer to run. In-lining reduces the conversions footprint by about 20%, but we're still looking at 25% of the time to process these lines is converting the timestamp to `datetime` format (with `total_seconds()` consuming another ~5% on top of that).

I may end up just writing a custom timestamp to seconds conversion to bypass `datetime` entirely, unless someone has another bright idea?

Comment: Have you checked how much of these 3 minutes is spent for instantiating ```datetime``` again and again, not parsing the data? ;) I'm not sure whether you can boost it further without changing the approach itself... Like multiprocessing or simply not creating a ```datetime``` for each line.

Comment: Have you considered [multiprocessing chunks](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map)?

Comment: @Art ~25% of the time was spent parsing and instantiating `datetime` objects, that was the problem.

Comment: @PeterWood Yeah, I'm not very familiar with it, but if you've got a solution maintainable for the uninitiated I'd be interested. That could only improve our processing time.

Comment: I'd close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070900/python-datetime-strptime-eating-lots-of-cpu-time except that the timestamp format is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I kept looking and I've found a module that does a fantastic job:

Introducing [ciso8601](https://github.com/closeio/ciso8601):

```
from ciso8601 import parse_datetime
...
ltime = parse_datetime(sline[time_col].strip())
```

Which, via cProfile:

```
       1    0.254    0.254  123.795  123.795 <string>:1(<module>)
20000423    4.188    0.000    4.188    0.000 {ciso8601.parse_datetime}
```

which is ~84x faster than the naive approach via `datetime.strptime()`... which is not surprising, given they [wrote a C module to do it](https://hack.close.io/posts/ciso8601).

Comment: ```Since it's written as a C module, it is much faster ...``` :D

Comment: Obviously, this is a great solution if your string representation is ISO and you can compile the module on your platform. Not everyone stumbling onto this question will necessarily be in that situation. Still, it's a nice find, and probably useful for the majority.

Comment: @JohnY Given the performance bump, I'd be surprised if it doesn't beat most other methods even if you have to convert the string to ISO8601 first.

Comment: For some, the requirement that you have to compile the C module will be the hurdle that prevents its use.

Comment: @JohnY you can pip install it via `pip install ciso8601`... but I'm still open to other options if you have them.

Comment: I think you are not getting the point. Some people *cannot* `pip install ciso8601`. Most significantly, it is a source-only distribution on PyPI, so some portion of Windows users will have trouble with it. Then there are more severe cases like mine, where I'm using a custom port of Python on a far-out-of-mainstream platform, so I am likely to run into even more difficulties than Windows users. Basically, anything that isn't a 100% pure-Python solution is impractical for me. (And even some things that would be 100% pure except for CPython standard library features are still out of my reach.)

Answer (score 0):

Two other things you could do (not fast, but at least convenient to code):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse, isoparse

parse(s)  # quite slow, but more flexible
isoparse(s)  # faster, but requires iso format and not as fast as cisco8601
```