# Reverse slice from end of list to a specific index

Tags: python, slice

Let's say I need a slice from the end of a sequence `seq` to the first occurrence of a given item `x` (inclusive). The naive attempt to write `seq[-1:seq.index(x)-1:-1]` creates a subtle bug:

```
seq = 'abc'
seq[-1:seq.index('b')-1:-1]  # 'cb' as expected
seq[-1:seq.index('a')-1:-1]  # '' because -1 is interpreted as end of seq
```

Is there any idiomatic way to write this?

`seq[seq.index(x):][::-1]` works fine, but it is presumably inefficient for large sequences since it creates an extra copy. (I do need a sequence in the end, so one copy is necessary; I just don't want to create a second copy.)

On a side note, this is a really easy bug to introduce, it can pass many tests, and is undetectable to any static analyzer (unless it warns about every slice with a negative step).

**Update**

There seems to be no perfect / idiomatic solution. I agree that it may not be the bottleneck as often as I thought, so I'll use `[pos:][::-1]` in most cases. When performance is important, I'd use the normal `if` check. However, I'll accept the solution that I found interesting even though it's hard to read; it's probably usable in certain rare cases (where I really need to fit the whole thing into an expression, and I don't want to define a new function).

Also, I tried timing this. For lists it seems there's always a 2x penalty for an extra slice even if they are as short as 2 items. For strings, the results are *extremely* inconsistent, to the point that I can't say anything:

```
import timeit
for n in (2, 5, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000):
    c = list(range(n))
    # c = 'x' * n
    pos = n // 2 # pretend the item was found in the middle
    exprs = 'c[pos:][::-1]', 'c[:pos:-1] if pos else c[::-1]'
    results = [timeit.Timer(expr, globals=globals()).autorange() for expr in exprs]
    times = [t/loops for loops, t in results]
    print(n, times[0]/times[1])
```

Results for lists (ratio of extra slice / no extra slice times):

```
2 2.667782437753884
5 2.2672817613246914
10 1.4275235266754878
100 1.6167102119737584
1000 1.7309116253903338
10000 3.606259720606781
100000 2.636049703318956
1000000 1.9915776615090277
```

Of course, this ignores the fact that whatever it is we're doing with the resulting slice is much more costly, in relative terms, when the slice is short. So still, I agree that for sequences of small size, `[::-1]` is usually perfectly fine.

Comment: `seq[seq.index(x):][::-1]` (or `reversed(seq[seq.index(x):])`) is the Pythonic way, as [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Comment: @TemporalWolf I agree in general. But there's a limit to how inefficient you should make your code even in its first iteration. Adding completely unnecessary slices to the code with the idea that someone will spend their time finding and optimizing it away in the future is not a good style, IMO.

Comment: It provides no improvement to the big-O performance, it's still `O(n)`, so it will still scale at the same rate... and if you're operating on sequences long enough to see a benefit, I doubt your `O(n)` operations are going to be the bottlenecks.

Comment: @TemporalWolf hmm you may have a point.. I suppose if the sequences are very large, and dealing with them represents a bottleneck, it's worth rewriting this with `numpy`/`pandas`/cython/C in many cases. I guess, it's not unreasonable to just add `[::-1]` in many cases.

Comment: On a 100M character long string, it takes 10ms on [repl.it](https://repl.it/IYVv/0). So your optimization would save 5ms per 100 million characters.

Comment: @TemporalWolf well, my concern was mostly modest-sized sequences (like hundreds of items) but in a tight inner loop.  My hesitation comes from the fact that it's hard to predict whether any given code might end up being reused, and called, some day, from a tight loop.

Comment: With sequences that short, the extra slice may not be substantially more expensive than other ways of handling the edge case, and the copying may not even be the most expensive part of the operation.

Comment: As an example for when it is time to do optimization, see [Fast conversion of timestamps for duration calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43216751/fast-conversion-of-timestamps-for-duration-calculation). Until you know what your bottleneck is, you shouldn't be optimizing.

Comment: @user2357112 actually, it seems it's always roughly 2x longer to do the extra copy, even if the sequence is as short as 2 items. See my update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an iterator result is okay, use a forward slice and call `reversed` on it:

```
reversed(seq[seq.index(whatever):])
```

If it isn't, subtract an extra `len(seq)` from the endpoint:

```
seq[:seq.index(whatever)-len(seq)-1:-1]
```

Or just take a forward slice, slice it again to reverse it, and eat the cost of the extra copy. It's probably not your bottleneck.

Whatever you do, leave a comment explaining it so people don't reintroduce the bug when editing, and write a unit test for this case.

Comment: Oh right, subtracting `len(seq)` from the endpoint works. It would most definitely need a comment, though, it's not obvious at all! I wish python slice handled this better, but I'm 20 years too late to propose a fix :)

Comment: The performance boost you see from using the second is almost guaranteed to not offset the additional maintenance burden.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I do agree the maintenance burden of this is very high.

Comment: @max Also, according to [repl.it](https://repl.it/IYVv/1), it's slower. So it's a lose-lose.

Comment: @TemporalWolf: It seems to be only slower for the edge case, since for the edge case, `seq[seq.index(whatever):]` with a string `seq` just returns `seq` without making a copy.

Comment: It's interesting, even forcing an almost complete copy they are [essentially comparable](https://repl.it/IYVv/2): I see <5% improvement.

Comment: @user2357112  `seq[seq.index(whatever):]` will never return the original `seq`, it must make a copy due to the semantic promise of slice.

Comment: @max: Slicing doesn't promise to return a new object. The built-in sequence types promise that mutating a slice won't affect the original object, but for immutable sequences, this promise doesn't actually require the creation of a new object. [Here's a demo.](http://ideone.com/RsSfcN)

Comment: You'll even find that with a string `s`, `copy.copy(s) is copy.deepcopy(s) is s`. (The `copy` module documentation should really say more about the semantics of trying to copy immutable objects.)

Comment: @user2357112 Omg you're right of course. There's never a need to promise to make a *copy* of an object; the only useful promise is that mutating one object is not going to affect the other. I know that's how `+` etc. work on `int` or `str`, but somehow I didn't apply the same logic to `slice` :)

Comment: @TemporalWolf try the timing for lists, though, instead of strings. It seems a consistent and material cost is paid by using the extra slice.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, `seq[seq.index(x):][::-1]` is the most readable solution, but here's a way that's a little more efficient.

```
def sliceback(seq, key):
    pos = seq.index(key)
    return seq[:pos-1 if pos else None:-1]

seq = 'abc'
for k in seq:
    print(k, sliceback(seq, k))
```

**output**

```
a cba
b cb
c c
```

---

As Budo Zindovic mentions in the comments, `.index` will raise an exception if the char isn't found in the string. Depending on the context, the code may not ever be called with a char that's not in `seq`, but if it's possible we need to handle it. The simplest way to do that is to catch the exception:

```
def sliceback(seq, key):
    try:
        pos = seq.index(key)
    except ValueError:
        return ''
    return seq[:pos-1 if pos else None:-1]

seq = 'abc'
for k in 'abcd':
    print(k, sliceback(seq, k))
```

**output**

```
a cba
b cb
c c
d
```

Python exception handling is very efficient. When the exception isn't actually raised it's faster than equivalent `if`-based code, but if the exception is raised more than 5-10% of the time it's faster to use an `if`.

Rather than testing for `key` before calling `seq.index`, it's more efficient to use `find`. Of course, that will only work if `seq` is a string; it won't work if `seq` is a list because (annoyingly) lists don't have a `.find` method.

```
def sliceback(seq, key):
    pos = seq.find(key)
    return '' if pos < 0 else seq[:pos-1 if pos else None:-1]
```

Comment: This has the advantage of making the `pos == 0` handling more explicit, hopefully making it more likely that people will realize why it's there. (On the other hand, people have to understand that `None` is equivalent to an omitted endpoint.)

Comment: I don't agree with the edit. Rather than catching the `ValueError`, I say we should let the exception propagate.

Comment: Performance wise, I'm seeing ~10% improvement over the simple solution by using sliceback: [repl.it](https://repl.it/IYVv/3)

Comment: @user2357112 Ok. Allowing the exception to bubble up makes sense too. I guess it depends on what the OP is doing with the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for `pos` while assigning the string, for example:

```
result = seq[-1:pos-1:-1] if pos > 0 else seq[::-1]
```

input:

```
pos = seq.index('a')
```

output:

```
cba
```

Comment: Yes of course. I was just hoping there might be something less verbose.

Comment: Be aware of the case for `pos` value when character isn't found.

Comment: Good point @BudoZindovic! I assume that since the OP is using `,index` rather than find that their code is correctly wrapped in a `try... except ValueError:` or has some other way to ensure that they don't supply chars that aren't in the string. ;)