# Reading millions of rows into a Panda Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am connecting to a Teradata DB and using Pandas to do some data analysis.  When i read in a table with 85k rows it reads into the dataframe in less than a minute.  However when I try this with a table that has 65 million rows the kernel just runs indefinitely. I am using Jupyter Notebook for the analysis.

Is there a better way to do this? Is this a Jupyter limitation or are dataframes not meant to handle that kind of volume? Or do I just need to be patient and let it load?  Here is how I am connecting, if that helps:

```
udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName="DataAnalysis", version="1.0", 
logConsole=True)
conn = udaExec.connect(method="xxxx", dsn="xxx", username=pwd.username, 
password=pwd.password)
sql_query = "Select * from Table_A"
data = pd.read_sql(sql_query,conn)
```

Thanks

Comment: How much data is there per row

Comment: @NickA it's like 10-12 columns in the table. Mix of Integer, Varchar (less than 250) and Timestamp

Comment: Are you sure it's running indefinitely, or it just takes a long time? If 85k rows takes a minute, then 65m would take almost 13 hours.

Comment: So about 100 bytes per row we'll say, that's 6.5GB of data/memory before you take into account how its stored etc,  how long do you expect it to take?

Comment: @TemporalWolf  can't argue with math.  By "indefinitely" I meant I killed it at about 25 mins.  I am thinking this is not the type of table I should be using pandas/dataframe for analyzing. i was just practicing around.  Thanks

Comment: @JD2775 Python's [standard date parser is really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43216751/3579910)... and it looks like pandas doesn't let you override it in `read_sql` like you can in `read_csv`.